# Lag when ScrollViewers manipulation mode set to control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mvvm, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

I'm using the MVVM model in which I've got a ScrollViewer which manipulationProperty I set to control when I wish to move an item around within the ScrollViewer. However when I set the ScrollViewer manipulationProperty to control whenever I move the item it lags. Is there an way to avoid this lag, or move my object around with the ScrollViewer active?

The problem with having the scrollViewer active while moving the item is that I can only translate the item while I'm within the item, once I go outside the Item the ScrollViewer takes over which I do not wish to happen.

I've got my scrollViewer around an map:

```
  <ScrollViewer Width="768" Height="380" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
            <Map/>
  </ScrollViewer>
```

Within this map I add an unit, which is the item I move around. I've created a ViewModel for the unit and it is in this ViewModel I move the unit around throung Manipulation Started/Delta/Completed:

```
   ManipulationStarted(ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
var myScrollViewer = FindParentOfType<ScrollViewer>(UnitViewModelSel) as ScrollViewer;
            myScrollViewer.SetValue(ScrollViewer.ManipulationModeProperty, ManipulationMode.Control);

 public void ManDelta(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        Point fingerPosition = e.DeltaManipulation.Translation;

        Unit.x = fingerPosition.X + Unit.x;
        Unit.y = fingerPosition.Y + Unit.y;

    }

public void ManCompleted(ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        var myScrollViewer = FindParentOfType<ScrollViewer>(UnitViewModel) as ScrollViewer;
        myScrollViewer.SetValue(ScrollViewer.ManipulationModeProperty, ManipulationMode.System);

    }
```

Comment: `However when I set the ScrollViewer manipulationProperty to control whenever I move the item it lags` That's the very reason why the default value of this property is `System`. With `System`, the scrolling is smooth thanks to hardware acceleration, but you have no or limited control over it. With `Control`, you let the control handle the scrolling, at the expense of smoothness. It's all about compromise.

Comment: @KooKiz So how would you move an unit with the ScrollViewer?

Comment: I'm not sure. Have you tried with `ScrollViewer.VerticalOffsetProperty` and `ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffsetProperty`?

Comment: @KooKiz No, but how should that help move an unit, when I select it?